# How to activate buttons from a AJAX PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is activating a button from a AJAX PHP page will work? at the end of the table row there will be a button to submit its form content to work with other AJAX Jquery functions but i dont why its not working in my code i tried using `onclick` a href works but linking to a page i really dont know to use AJAX very well im starting to learn it hoping somone could understand this. Thank you for being polite i dont know if this is already asked i tried searching for this also thats why i asked..

**HTML**

```
<input type = "text" name = "search_text" id = "search_text">             
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>lastname</th>
                    <th>middlename</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th></th>

                </tr> 
              </thead>
              <tbody  id = "result">

        </table>
```

**JQUERY** to display fetched data and to output it

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
     var txt =$(this).val(); 
     if(txt != ''){
         $.ajax({
            url: "datas.php",
            method: "post",
            data:{search:txt},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
         });
     }
  });
function myFunction(){
   alert('Working!')
}
```

**PHP is** i didnt include the connection so you will not think im trying a SQL injection or hacking i didn't even know will it work im a student not a hacker though

```
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){


                $output .='<tr>
                            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>   
                            <td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td>   
                            <td>'.$row["middlename"].'</td> 
                            <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>    
                            <td><button type = "submit" onclick="myFunction()" class = "btn btn-default" ><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></em></button></td>  
                          </tr>
                     ';

        }
        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the whole JS code, or at least a bit more to try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: thats all i used when adding `setInterval` always refresh cant do anything

Comment: how do you activate this `AJAX` from the html you posted?

Comment: sorry i forgot i have this for search

Comment: Don't you need the `data` within your `ajax` function?, it's a `POST` request.

Comment: sorry my bad wrong copy paste

Comment: Really not at all clear what isn't working

Comment: It's working for me now, what's printing in the browser console?, maybe the `$output` isn't getting data and you see it just as an empty string.

Comment: submit button isn't working?

Comment: i didnt have that error.. i tried this `onclick="myFunction()"` `function myFunction(){ alert('working')}`

Comment: you want to select data by what is typed in the input right?

Comment: its working +julekgwa